Zerobrane thows error when running any code
I am new to Lua and Zerobrane.
Whenever I run a program that I have written, I get the log output:
Program starting as '"/app/share/zbstudio/bin/linux/x64/lua" -e "io.stdout:setvbuf('no')" "/home/kass/Downloads/Programming/Lua/Learning/main.lua"'.
Program 'lua' started in '/home/kass/Downloads/Programming/Lua/Learning' (pid: 81).
execvp(/app/share/zbstudio/bin/linux/x64/lua, -e, io.stdout:setvbuf('no'), /home/kass/Downloads/Programming/Lua/Learning/main.lua) failed with error 2!
Program completed in 0.02 seconds (pid: 81).

I know my code is valid because if I run the code through my terminal/online interpreter, it works perfectly fine
I tried to change the interpreter, and I've look at the docs for settings to try changing, but I haven't found anything.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I fixed the issue by switching to the download from the website, instead of using the Flatpak version.
